# WPF Vb.net Copyto not working?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, copy, startup, startup-folder

I am simply tyring to fire an event that copies a program to the Startup folder. I do not understand where I am going wrong? I keep on getting exception message. The file that is being copies is NOT in use.

```
 Try
        Dim DesktopLink As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        Dim StartupFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)

 Dim info As New FileInfo(StartupFolder)
            info.CopyTo(DesktopLink + "\doessomething.bat")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error: Can not copy to startup folder")
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're creating a `FileInfo` from a *folder*, not a *file*.

This should likely be:

```
Dim info As New FileInfo(Path.Combine(StartupFolder, "doessomething.bat"))
info.CopyTo(Path.Combine(DesktopLink, "doessomething.bat"))
```

Or, even easier:

```
Dim source = Path.Combine(StartupFolder, "doessomething.bat")
Dim target = Path.Combine(DesktopLink, "doessomething.bat")
File.Copy(source, target)
```